# Lua print on the same line

Tags: lua

In Pascal, I have `write` and `writeln`. Apparently Lua's `print` is similar to `writeln` of Pascal. Do we have something similar to `write` of Pascal? How can consecutive print commands send their output to the same line?

```
print("Hello")
print("World")
```

Output:

```
Hello
world
```

I want to have this:

```
Hello world
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use `io.write` instead `print`, which is meant for simple uses, like debugging, anyway.

Comment: well, that is why @lhf is one of creators of Lua language. :)

Answer (score 26):

Expanding on [lhf's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148678/lua-print-on-the-same-line/7148723#7148723), the `io` library is preferred for production use.

The `print` function in the base library is implemented as a primitive capability. It allows for quick and dirty scripts that compute something and print an answer, with little control over its presentation. Its principle benefits are that it coerces all arguments to `string` and that it separates each argument in the output with tabs and supplies a newline.

Those advantages quickly become defects when detailed control of the output is required. For that, you really need to use `io.write`. If you mix `print` and `io.write` in the same program, you might trip over another defect. `print` uses the C `stdout` file handle explicitly. This means that if you use `io.output` to change the output file handle, `io.write` will do what you expect but `print` won't.

A good compromise can be to implement a replacement for `print` in terms of `io.write`. It could look as simple as this untested sample where I've tried to write clearly rather than optimally and still handle `nil` arguments "correctly":

```
local write = io.write
function print(...)
    local n = select("#",...)
    for i = 1,n do
        local v = tostring(select(i,...))
        write(v)
        if i~=n then write'\t' end
    end
    write'\n'
end
```

Once you are implementing your own version of `print`, then it can be tempting to improve it in other ways for your application. Using something with more formatting control than offered by `tostring()` is one good idea. Another is considering a separator other than a tab character.

Comment: This can also be written as `function print(...) io.write(table.concat({...},"\t"),"\n") end` at the cost of creating a table and performing a concatenation.

Comment: But only if all arguments are strings or numbers since [`table.concat`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/ltablib.c.html#tconcat) calls `lua_isstring()` on each element of the table... compared to the base library `print` which does call `tostring` on each parameter passed.

Comment: @Rberteig: whay do you use select("#",...) instead of just #arg?

Comment: The `arg` table was a feature of Lua 5.0, and present but deprecated in 5.1, where it only exists if referenced in a function. Referencing it causes a new table to be created since `...` is a very special value that is not a table. Also, `select('#',...)` gets the correct length even if some arguments are `nil` where `#arg` might not.

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative, just build up your string then write it out with a single `print`

You may not always have access to the `io` library.

Comment: If you don't have access to the `io` library, why would you have access to `print`?

Comment: Because you could be in an embedded environment, or some other restricted environment which redefines `print`. World of Warcraft for example.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Very easy to forget that this approach exists.

Answer (score 6):

You could use variables for "Hello" and "World".  Then concatenate them later.  Like this:

```
local h = "Hello"
local w = "World"

print(h..w)
```

It will be display, in this case, as "HelloWorld".  But that's easy to fix.  Hope this helped!

Comment: This will allocate memory - not a good idea for printing things out

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Searous's answer, try the following.

local h = "hello"
local w = "world"

print(h.." "..w)

You can concatenate both together, just concatenate a space between both variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
local h = "Hello"
local w = "World!"

print(h, w)
```

Comment: This outputs a tab between the two strings.